# Notify Command in ACL

Tags: acl

I noticed that the Attachment in the Notify command is not mandatory to use but if I exclude the attachment the script fails.  here is the script that i am currently using:

```
 NOTIFY USER "%v_sender_email_acct%" MAILBOX "%v_smtp_sever%" ADDRESS "%v_recv_email_addr%" SUBJECT "SAE Exception Report from Global T&E Audit Team" MESSAGE "%v_msg%" ATTACHMENT "SAE_Exception_Report.xlsx"
```

I tried running the script without an attachment it fails, please see the script:

```
 NOTIFY USER "%v_sender_email_acct%" MAILBOX "%v_smtp_sever%" ADDRESS "%v_recv_email_addr%" SUBJECT "SAE Exception Report from Global T&E Audit Team" MESSAGE "%v_msg%"
```

can you please tell me what do i have to do in order to remove the attachment?

Thank you for your help!

Regards,
Waseh